A question about Selmer group from Silverman's book


On page 334, silverman's book "Arithmetic of Elliptic curves".
The author shows in the corollary that the Selmer group is contained in another group (defined in the lemma 4.3).
Then in the remark, he says: to check whether $\xi$ is in the selmer group, we need to check whether $C(K_v)$ is nonempty for every $v \in S$.
My stupid question is that: do we need to check $C(K_v)$ nonempty for those $v$ not in $S$ (so $\xi$ are unramified with respect to those $v$, which means $\xi$ are trivial on inertia group $I_v$)?

For $v\notin S$, the homogeneous space $C$ associated to $v$ is non-singular modulo $v$, so it is a non-singular genus $1$ curve defined over the residue field $k_v$. Every such curve has a point, i.e., $C(k_v)\ne\emptyset$. But since $C\bmod v$ is non-singular, Hensel's lemma lets us lift a point in $C(k_v)$ to a point in $C(K_v)$. So $C(K_v)\ne\emptyset$ for all $v\notin S$.
